# install of Lighttpd in centos 404 error

Tags: lighttpd

I have installed Lighttpd in centos. Its fresh installed, and server is from digital ocean. 
For installation i took guide from howtoforge. which was suggested in one of the post in this site.

Now issue is i am keep getting 404 not found error. I havent even changed anything, so it should display the default welcome page? but still nothing.
I have disabled ipv6 in conf.file as per the guide.

If anyone can suggest me if i am missing anything from install guide.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things to check.

1. Inside of your lighttpd.conf make sure `server.document-root` is set to the location of your web root.
2. Make sure `index-file.names` is set something like `( "index.php", "index.html", "index.lighttpd.html" )` is good.
3. Create an index.html inside of your webroot and see if it loads in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

Go to

```
sudo nano /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf
```

And uncomment:

```
server.max-fds = 2048
```

Restart the service
- a way could be `service lighttpd restart`

Answer (score 0):

The default root location from where the server stats is:

```
var.server_root = "/var/www"
server.document-root = server_root + "/htdocs"
```

So you must put your `index.html` in `/var/log/www/htdocs` directory